# sharing a queue between two java projects running on two different machines

Tags: java, queue, distributed-computing

Currently I have a project which uses a queue to store and retrieve .
Now I have to split into two projects in which one stores details into the queue and other project retrieves from the queue to execute.
How can I do that ? 
should the queue be global to both the projets?
How to make queue  available to both the projects ?
two projects should run on two different machines .
and how to invoke second project from the first .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you could do would be to introduce your queue as a third project. Essentially, this would be a queue behind a Web Service or Server (think sockets).

The wrapper will make your queue available across different domains, which can be then consumed by your current two projects.

Comment: how do i invoke one project from another ?

Comment: @HariVenkatesh: You would have your queue project as a web service or server and expose it through a network connection. Your other two projects would in turn make use of the network connection to add and remove elements from the queue. Strictly speaking none of the projects will be referencing each other, however they will be aware of the common endpoint.